# Multi-layer views results

Tags: views

I'm not quite sure how to explain this but here goes. I want to have a link to a view that displays a collection of categories i.e. t-shirts, jeans, socks, sunglasses etc. I then want to (for example) click on t-shirts and be prestented with a list of all links to items/nodes that are t-shirts. Is views able to do this 2 tier result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with a Contextual filter in Views.

Create a Content View of your desired nodes, then add a Contextual Filter (I'm assuming your categories are actually Taxonomy terms referenced from nodes) for the Field with that Taxonomy reference.

Configure it with these options:
    `When the filter value is NOT available`
    **Display a summary**
    `Format` **List**
    `Base path` (you *must* enter the Page path if this isn't the first Page Display in your Views)
    **Display record count with link**
    `More`
    **Transform spaces to dashes in URL**

This way you get a list of term IDs that link through to a list of nodes tagged with those terms.

You probably want the term name to be displayed instead of the term ID. In that case remove the Contextual filter, we'll add the one for Taxonomy term Name, but we need a Relationship first for that information to become available.

So add a Relationship **Taxonomy term referenced from field_category** (or whatever the field is called in your case), require it if you don't want summary results without a category.

Then add a Contextual filter **Name** from `Taxonomy term` Category, it will use the Relationship we created, and configure it like above.

Comment: Thank you so much for the comprehensive answer, much appreciated. I will get to try it out in a couple of days and respond.

Comment: I have set this up and added a "filter criteria" to show only terms belonging to a particular parent term. Is there a way of adding the taxonomy image form each term to display next to each link?

Comment: If you mean to change the Summary links of the Contextual Filter, then I guess you have to override it in a custom module or through your theme: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21themes%21stable%21templates%21views%21views-view-summary.html.twig/8.6.x You could probably make it display the icon alone, but to combine you probably have to do some more work. Overriding Contextual output isn't as easy as overriding Field output. Maybe this would be a great new question to ask ;)